# csv to json, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

```
!python evaluation/mpd2csv.py --mpd_path "data" --out_path "data"

#mpd2csv.py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Convert MPD")
parser.add_argument('--mpd_path', default=None, required=True)
tracks_file = open(path.join(args.out_path, 'tracks.csv'), 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
tracks_writer = csv.writer(tracks_file)

with open("data/tracks.csv", encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data=json_file.read()
```

error: ' json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

I want to change the tracks.csv file to a json file. But there's been an error. How can you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have made a sample csv as your requirement. It looks like

[image: sample dataframe by littinrajan]

Below code will convert tracks.csv to tracks.json

> **Code:**

```
#import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import json

#reading csv using pandas
tracks = pd.read_csv('tracks.csv')
#diplay csv
print(tracks)

#converting dataframe to json
json_data = tracks.to_json(orient='records')

#saving json data to the file tracks.json
with open('tracks.json','w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_data, json_file)
```

You can read tracks.json by below code

> **Code**:

```
#read json file
with open('tracks.json','r') as json_file:
    data = json_file.read()
json_output = json.loads(data)
print(json_output)
```

> **Output:**

```
[{"tracknumber":1,"count":2},{"tracknumber":2,"count":4},{"tracknumber":3,"count":6},{"tracknumber":4,"count":8},{"tracknumber":5,"count":10}]
```

Validated output:

[image: Validated json by littinrajan]

I hope this would be helpfull.

Comment: For validating json you can use Online JSON Validator. Link: https://jsonlint.com/